# Preview report from the IDE in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm just getting started creating reports for a VB.NET application in Visual Studio.  I get that you have to put a report viewer control on a form and bind the report to it when running the application but when developing the report, how do you just preview it without running the app and then the report?  I have it open in design mode but for the life of me I can't figure out how to preview it while developing.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe there is a way of doing this. You just have design view and then running your application with test data. There's no way to display the report with data at design time AFAIK

Comment: Well that's annoying, thanks for the response.